# Using Gstreamer RTSP server in android for livestreaming

Tags: android, gstreamer, rtsp, live-streaming, android-mediacodec

I am completely new to Gstreamer.
Can some expert just help me understand if i can use the RTSP in gstreamer for livestreaming.
I want to use mediacodec API in android to capture data and then use gstreamer RTSP for streaming the live captured content (h264 / AAC)

Comment: Hi! Were you able to get the stream from a RTSP connection?